# How to plot a continuous sine wave in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, waveform

I am trying to simulate the display of a sine wave one would generate from an oscilloscope using Python. As I am trying to merely simulate it (and not pull the data from the oscilloscope), I was wondering how I would show a continuous sine wave. I have the sample rate of the device (200MHz - 1GS/s), the frequency of my wave (1MHz), and the amplitude (1V). The data would be viewed in microseconds. I have read through various answers here on StackOverflow and have had problems with the plot having irregular waves or something of the sort. Is there a way to have this data shown like below? [image: Oscilloscope data output I wish to simulate, for 1MHz freq, 100MS/s sample rate, amplitude of 1V.]

A secondary problem is the ability to plot this wave continuously. For example, when using Matplotlib, if I zoom out it doesn't show the wave continuing past my interval. Is there a way to have the wave continually represented? I don't want to be tied down to Matplotlib, so I am looking for other solutions that continually creating (appending?) data in both directions. If this is not possible, is it possible to establish some sort of number of wavelengths in each direction?

Thank you so much!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Fs = 20E3
f = 1E6
sample = Fs/f
print(sample)
x = np.arange(sample)

y = 100*np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Are you in Windows or Linux ?

Comment: Do you want one image or do you want to have a dynamic display ?

Comment: @Soleil I'm in Windows! I want to have a dynamic display optimally, but I think the problem is more with defining how many wavelengths I need in the waveform.

Comment: @NickA My code has been edited above, but it is not fitting my needs at the moment. This is based off of other threads I've read, and I'm unsure of how to cater to my problem.

Comment: @Imas That's alright, providing code (even if it doesn't do what you want it to do), allows other users to more easily develop code that fits in with what you're doing in a way that you can understand, it also shows that you've given the problem some thought and research before coming to SO

Comment: For static display, you got many options, including gnuplot, matplotlib. For dynamic display, you'll need to choose a framework, such as WPF (if you can stick to windows), or if you want something multiplatform, use a javascript plot library + electron (or a website), and feed the data as you receive it. It's interesting to do this with electron or website since you can have as many virtual screen as you want (eg for each student of a class),

Comment: and you're not stuck to windows: you can also make a mobile app, access to the website from phones and tablets. You don't need to have a domain name, but just a webserver (such as nginx or IIS). With WPF however IMO it's more simple. So... what do you want ?

Comment: For javascript plot: https://plot.ly/javascript/

Comment: About electron and keep using your python code, you're lucky: https://github.com/fyears/electron-python-example

Comment: The drawback with python is that you're not multithread, and that's really helpful when you got things happening in parallel: 1) signal generation 2) display 3) user interface. Doing the same with several processes is harder.

Comment: @Imas can you explain "the problem is more with defining how many wavelengths I need in the waveform" ?

Comment: Hi Soleil. Thanks for the responses! I am using Plotly to visualize the data, but the problem lies more in generating the sine wave. At a high frequency, the waveform goes berserk - I wanted to know if there was a particular module that creates waveforms based on frequencies and amplitudes. I also want to be able to define how many wavelengths I want - for example, I can ask for 5 different wavelengths of the graph, so I'd be able to make the waveform as long as possible.

Comment: @Imas you might want to give code and numbers for the high frequency berserks. I'm afraid you'll have to code this module yourself. I think the best would be to have a basic WPF program, since it's really adapted for user interfaces, multithreading, and so on. You can display waveforms at 60fps, I guess this will be sufficient. You can use polyline to display your waves. Writing a webapp would be a bit cumbersome. Even though it would be useful for the others.

Comment: Your code above won't plot anything, given that `np.arange(20e3/1e6)` will return `array([ 0. ])`.  It looks like you want f to be your wave frequency, and Fs to be your sampling frequency.  Why is your sampling frequency *lower* than your wave frequency?  Your waveform won't look very good if you do that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`matplotlib.animation`](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) to achieve your goal.

I took an [existing example which emulates an oscilloscope](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/strip_chart_demo.html) and adjusted it to your needs (e.g. sine wave & plotting continously).

Regarding the continous plotting: I set up a `continous` variable, where you can choose if you want to plot it continously (not able to zoom) or not (able to zoom). I wasn't able to combine both functionalities in one plot yet. So just run the code once with `continous = True` and once with `continous = False` to see if it suits your needs.

But I think this could be a good start for plotting continous sine waves.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Your Parameters
amp = 1         # 1V        (Amplitude)
f = 1000        # 1kHz      (Frequency)
fs = 200000     # 200kHz    (Sample Rate)
T = 1/f
Ts = 1/fs

# Select if you want to display the sine as a continous wave
#  True = Continous (not able to zoom in x-direction)
#  False = Non-Continous  (able to zoom)
continous  = True

x = np.arange(fs)
y = [ amp*np.sin(2*np.pi*f * (i/fs)) for i in x]


class Scope(object):
    def __init__(self, ax, maxt=2*T, dt=Ts):
        self.ax = ax
        self.dt = dt
        self.maxt = maxt
        self.tdata = [0]
        self.ydata = [0]
        self.line = Line2D(self.tdata, self.ydata)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-amp, amp)
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, self.maxt)

    def update(self, y):
        lastt = self.tdata[-1]
        if continous :
            if lastt > self.tdata[0] + self.maxt:
                self.ax.set_xlim(lastt-self.maxt, lastt)

        t = self.tdata[-1] + self.dt
        self.tdata.append(t)
        self.ydata.append(y)
        self.line.set_data(self.tdata, self.ydata)
        return self.line,


def sineEmitter():
    for i in x:
        yield y[i]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scope = Scope(ax)

# pass a generator in "sineEmitter" to produce data for the update func
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, scope.update, sineEmitter, interval=10,
                              blit=True)

plt.show()
```